# Loosely-coupled, non-referenced assembly - how to make sure it's in the \bin\Debug folder of the exe project for debugging?

Tags: c#, build, reference

I'm building a loosely-coupled app, where the main exe project only contains references to an assembly with interfaces.  The concrete implementations of those interfaces are in assemblies that are referenced indirectly - via IoC.  However, those assemblies' build output doesn't get copied to the `bin\Debug` folder of the exe, which means my IoC can't find them.

How do I make sure those assemblies are copied, if there is no actual project/assembly reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [post-build event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx) to copy the desired files to the output directory after the project is built.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to right click your exe project -> Project Dependencies.
Then tick all the projects that you need to be copied over your bin\Debug folder ?

Alternatively what Konamiman said would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure they are built before the main exe project by checking the relevant projects in *Build Dependencies* dialog (found in the Project context menu).

However I think you need to use `xcopy` in a post-build step to actually copy the assemblies.